# Repeated vector names in loop error

Tags: r

I am running the following code over pairs of files like `a1.txt and b1.txt`, `a2.txt and b2.txt`, .... `a999.txt and b999.txt`:

```
dostuff <- function(x) 
{
files <- list.files(pattern=paste('.', x, '\\.txt', sep=''))
a <- read.table(files[1],header=FALSE)  #file a1.txt 
G <- a$V1-a$V2
b <- read.table(files[2],header=FALSE) #file b1.txt
as.factor(b$V2)
q <- tapply(b$V3,b$V2,Fun=length)
H <- b$V1-b$V2
model <- lm(G~H)
return(model$coefficients[2],q)
}

results <- sapply(0:999,dostuff)
Error in tapply(b$V3, b$V2, FUN = length) : arguments must have same length
```

This I assume is because both files in a pair have no headers so `a` has `V1 V2` and `b` has `V1 V2 V3`. 
However this error does not arise when i run this over small batches of files like `0:3` and the results for these come out the same as if i did every analysis separately, clearing the environment between runs of the whole code manually.

I believe the problem arises once files run from `a1 b1` to `a10 b10` and above. Because the loop i thinks get confused over which files to select. This problem disappears as long as I run with `a0 b0` to `a9 b9`.

Best solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered similar issues when there was some stray file in a batch I was trying to process that didn't have the expected number of rows. I'd recommend checking the dimensions of all your files first to see if they all agree. My guess is that files 0-3 are all properly formatted, but maybe some file in [0, 999] isn't.

Try checking to see if the dimensions are the same for all files:

```
dims2 <- list()
dims3 <- list()
doDims <- function(x){
  files <- list.files(pattern=paste('.', x, '\\.txt', sep=''))
  a <- read.table(files[1],header=FALSE)  #file a1.txt 
  G <- a$V1-a$V2
  b <- read.table(files[2],header=FALSE) #file b1.txt
  as.factor(b$V2)
  dims2[x] <- dim(b$V2)
  dims3[x] <- dim(b$V3)
}
```

Then you can see if all the dimensions are, indeed, what you expect.

Comment: thanks feff i found the problem but not sure how to correct it maybe you can help.  The loop runs fine as long as files 'a0.txt' `b0.txt` run up to `a9.txt' `b9.txt'.  But if i go up to `a10` and 'b10' this is then it get confused.

Comment: Not sure what the issue would be there without knowing more details. Do those files exist? Or are the properly formatted? I don't really have any information to be able to help here.